# How to bind key in use-package

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, use-package

I added a section binding to my config, but one key doesn't work.

```lisp
:bind (("C-c a" . org-agenda)
       ("<f6>"  . org-capture)
       ("<M-S-return>" . org-insert-subheading))
```

These two keys (`C-c a`, `f6`) work as I expected.

If I check the <kbd>M-S-return</kbd> key binding via `C-h k`, the help will show the `org-insert-todo-heading` binding.

How do I bind <kbd>M-S-return</kbd> to `org-insert-subheading`?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. Could someone please check (and close if so)? And does it really matter whether `use-package` is used? Isn't this just a question about binding `<M-S-return>`?

Comment: @Drew possibly more about when org-insert-todo-heading is bound to a key it might be after use-package if lazy loading occurs

Comment: By default, the `:bind` mechanism in `use-package` uses the global  map. It works fine for the first two, since `org-mode` does not touch them, but it doesn't work in the third case, because `org-mode` does touch that. And I'm pretty sure @Drew is right and I'm also pretty sure I 've answered a question similar to this, but for the life of me, I can't find it now...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for telling me about the different types of maps.

The issue is as @NickD pointed out in [their answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59269/9874) and the example *use-package* code puts all the bindings into the global map.
ie org-mode puts the binding to `<M-S-return>` in org-mode-map so you need to use that map.

Because my configuration is based on *use-package*, it is more convenient for me to use this framework's approaches. So I added `:map` to my configuration and everything worked.

```lisp
:bind (("C-c a" . org-agenda)
       ("<f6>"  . org-capture)
       :map org-mode-map
       ("<M-S-return>" . org-insert-subheading))
```

Answer (score 4):

The mode sets up its own keymap which overrides the global map. The `:bind` mechanism creates a binding in the global map, but in an Org mode file, the key is looked up in the mode map *before* the global map, so you get the definition in the mode map.

The usual way to override this is by using the [mode hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks). Add to your init file the following code:

```el
(eval-after-load 'org '(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-return>") #'org-insert-subheading))))
```

The mode hook (`org-mode-hook` in this case) is run at the end of the mode function (`org-mode` in this case). "Running" the hook executes each function in the hook. In this case, when the function call is evaluated, it calls `define-key` to redefine the given key (`(kbd "<M-S-return>")`) in the given keymap (`org-mode-map`) to the given command (`#'org-insert-subheading`). And that is done *after* the mode function has set up the mode map, so it overrides whatever the mode function did.

Hooks are an important customization method in Emacs: you should read the "Hooks" section of the manual (well, you should read the *whole* manual eventually). And BTW, you can get to the "Hooks" section of the manual *in Emacs*: `C-h r i Hooks RET`.

Comment: As you are saying that the unwanted map is not global but in org-mode-map then this can be set in use-package bind by giving that map explicitly

Comment: @mmmmmm: I don't know much about `use-package` - feel free to add an answer (or edit my answer) to add information about how to do it  in the use-package declaration. That might be a useful answer to have around.

Comment: see @dmin's answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59270/9874

Comment: Great - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You want `M-S-<return>`, not `<M-S-return>`.

Comment: I think it might be only relatively recently that `M-S-<return>` would work at all.  `<M-S-return>` is perfectly fine, and how Emacs itself describes it.

Comment: That is not the cause of the problem.